# Retrieve key when subkey equals a specifc value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a simpler than:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if($value['date']->ID == 22) { echo $key; }
}
```

for searching for `ID->22` (each `ID` is unique) and then if it exists, return the parent key? In this case it would be key 0:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 22                    
                )

        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 33                    
                )

        )

)
```

Just curious if there is a less intensive way of doing this as it will have to be done a lot on any given page. If not, is it practical to run 700 of these loops at once?

Comment: if the `ID` is supposed to be unique, just add `break;` if found

Comment: good idea, that would cut things down a bit

Comment: Can't you make the ID teh key? - At least, if you search a single array multiple times consider creating a lookup table (ID -> key or date entry) beforehand.

Comment: Wish I could, WordPress is generating the array.

Comment: You'll have to loop one way or another, you can only dress that loop up in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

This answer doesn't address the `Is there a simpler than:` part of this question. The `foreach` loop is more than likely the simplest way to do this. I am taking your question at the bottom of the answer `is [there] a less intensive way of doing this` as the real question.

As has been mentioned in comments you can use `break` to get out of the loop when you have a result, stopping any further unnecessary processing.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    if ($value->ID === 22)
    {
        echo $value->ID;
        break;
    }
}
```

Having your results sorted can also have a major impact on the performance of a loop like this. When you introduce conditional logic your processor tries to predict the result of the statement before it knows what the actual value of `$value->ID` is. If you allow it the means to predict this, you can make the loops much faster. This is called branch prediction. There is an excellent answer on SO about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) that will help you.